# How to update recoder to parquet file in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

When I regularly update the data to parquet file, the time spent will be more and more slowly.
How to fix it?

rdd.save("hdfs://hdfshost:9000/data/data.parquet", "parquet", SaveMode.Append)

First write, the recorders are 100w+, file size is 50MB.
After write, the recorders are 1w+. But,file size grows to 100MB＋

Help!